# Gmail iOS app: What’s a work around to *save* all my deleted gmail messages?

Tags: gmail

I want an easy way to save all of the messages I delete. Gmail automatically empties the trash after a few months. I want to keep all my deleted messages so I can find something several months later that didn’t seem important, but now is.
Can I create a script that will move the messages from the deleted or trash (or bin) folder to something like “archived forever” ?? Where Can I hired someone to do that?

I read most of my emails on an iPad and swipe to delete the messages. I know that I could select and move them to a folder that would not be deleted, but that’s a lot of work for the 75+ messages I get each day.

Thanks for any help... I can pay for quality help on this problem.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because It is about an iOS application.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you indicate to actually delete emails in Gmail (or move them to Trash), it actually simply changes the tag on an email to the 'All mail' tag. (some apps, like Apple Mail, give you a button to move to Trash). In the Gmail all, go to settings and change the swipe action to 'Archive'. This will remove the message from view, but will move it to 'All mail'. You can go into the 'All mail' folder to see all these archived emails.